# Navigate to Interface from Implementing Struct in GoLand

Tags: go, goland

Go by itself does not have any explicit way of specifying the interface name with the implementations.
But do IDEs like GoLand have a way to figure out the interface that a struct is implementing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, GoLand will allow you to jump to the interface that a struct implements. It works in the inverse too; it'll show you all of the types that implement an interface.

[image]

Comment: Wow. This is a lifesaver. Don't know why my eyes have always ignored that green circle. Thank you! If you know a keyboard shortcut, please do share that too.

Comment: Okay hovering on that icon it says the shortcut is Command+U. :)

Comment: It's definitely not the most obvious icon, and the context menu when you right-click on the struct name doesn't reveal an option to jump to the interface!

Answer (score 0):

Using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + T or Ctrl + ALT + B in Windows to display the pop-up box, you can choose whether to jump to the interface or implement it.
You can set your own keyboard shortcuts：
Settings-> keyboard mapping-> Navigation-> go to implementation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vch9U.png)